# Launch Image names of iPhoneX?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

A question about iPhoneX.  I want put  Launch Image of iPhoneX( 1125px × 2436px) in common folder. Not in LaunchImage source.   What's the  Launch Image names of iPhoneX? just like 'Default-iOS8-736h@3x', I can not found the name in  https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/ .

Comment: not in Images.xcassets

Comment: iPhone-X Default-812h@3x.png not used as splash screen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378187/iphone-x-default-812h3x-png-not-used-as-splash-screen

Comment: I add the image in a folder  of progect which  not in LaunchScreen.xib or image.xcassets.  In apple's  <<Guide and SImple code>>,  flow the example ,I add some code in Info.plist "UILaunchImages", the 1125px × 2436px  image works,  and the picture name does not matter.
 :                 <dict>
   <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>11.0</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
   <string>your iphonex name</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
   <string>Portrait</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
   <string>{375, 812}</string>
  </dict>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add static launch image for iPhone X, only add:
Default-375w-812h@3x.png

Comment: This should be the right answer. Just add a 1125x2436 image with the name Default-375w-812h@3x.png and the iPhone X version of the app will launch.

Comment: This should be the selected correct answer, adding Default-375w-812h@3x.png works.

Comment: Previously I had "Default-812h@3x.png" and it not worked, changed the name to Default-375w-812h@3x.png and worked, this is the right answer.

Comment: Could you tell me what's the landscape dimension naming convention for iPhone X ?

Answer (score 15):

Following the convention it should be named `Default-812h@3x.png` (and `Default-Landscape-812h@3x.png`) ([812 is the actual height in points](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)).
And looks like currently there is no way to use storyboard-powered launch screen and have pixel perfect images for both iPhone X and old plus sizes models.

Comment: What we do is create larger images with big margins and center rather than scale them, so they look pixel perfect, but with different margins on different devices.

Comment: ... using storyboard-powered launch screen, right?
So, usually it is a good idea, but it does not work for some designs, unfortunately. The problem here is that iPhone X and iPhone 6/7/8 Plus have different navigation bar design (height), so it cannot be "described" in storyboard terms because there is no way to differentiate the images (both of them has @3x suffix).

Comment: @ValentinShergin I used Default-812h@3x.png image size 1125x2436 but its still using Default-568h@2x.png in iPhone X splash...Cocos2d-x project...your answer not worked.

Comment: That is really strange. Do you compile it with Xcode 9 and with iOS 11 (using "iOS 11 SDK") support? How does the app looks like when it is running, it is running fullscreen or letterboxed?

Comment: And if your app supports landscape mode, you also probably have to add `Default-Landscape-812h@3x.png`.

Comment: its a portrait game, still using iphone5 splash in iPhoneX

Comment: Here is full source https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7BvUcbayKm2a3ZrMTZnYk1FNFk

Comment: Xcode project file path : Maths Game/cocos2d-x-3.15.1/Projects/Game Source/proj.ios_mac/TheFour.xcodeproj

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor I found this problem, too.  Do you have any solution?

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor for me it refers Default@2x.png always. Did you get solution?

Answer (score 8):

You can add static launch image for iPhone X with old project with simple step:

```
1, Select Assets.xcassets select launch image folder.
2, Check "iOS 8.0 and later" in the right Attribute inspector panel.
3, An iPhone X place holder will appear, drag an image 375w812h @ 3x to it and you are done.
```

Comment: It still work now on Xcode 9.1 9B55, you can try to clean the the build folder

Comment: worked !!! had to remove the launcsreen key from my .info file !!1 Thanks so much

Answer (score 7):

If the launchImage source name is 'LaunchImage'.
[image: setting in General Tab]

The name should be 
`[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-1100-2436h@3x.png"]`

PS:  how to find it ?

1. step 1. Open the bundle directory like `/Users/hite/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5CFE3CFA-94F8-45EC-BAC5-xxx2/`
2. Find your application file like `myFit.app`, and `Show Package Contents` .
3. search for the 3x.png to get the image name.

Comment: Following this method, the iPhone X’s launch image for portrait orientation is "LaunchImage-1100-Portrait-2436h@3x.png”.

Comment: 1. You can find your Simulator app file path by print `[NSBundle mainBundle]`; 2. Open your app with `Show Package Contents`, but not `unzip`

Answer (score 4):

You can define the names in your `Info.plist` using the `UILaunchImages` Key:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-812h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 812}</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Landscape images would work the same.

Comment: You are the master!
This is exactly what I needed. Brilliant. :)

Comment: after adding below tag, it is working now `<dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-812h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 812}</string>
    </dict>`